# new column which is min of two other columns if condition is True

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

if `df['freq']<10`
i want to transform all values in `"freq_new"` to the minimun between  `df["freq_cell"]` and `10`

I try this and it didnt work

```
df.loc[df['freq']<10,['freq_new']]=min((df["freq_cell"]/10),10)
```

Comment: why are you using ```df_```? Is the code failing or are you getting an unexpected result? Please provide reproducible code

Comment: mistake.   I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your code is incorrect. IIUC, you can use `loc` to locate where column 'freq' is less than 10, and create a new column called 'freq_new' which will be the minimum between 'freq_cell' and the value 10 using [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df.loc[df.freq < 10, 'frec_new'] = df['freq_cell'].clip(upper=10)
```

The code in the RHS says:
*return value from freq_cell but ceil it at 10 if it's bigger*. So the maximum will be 10.

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np 
`df.loc[df['freq']>10,'freq_new']=np.minimum((df['freq_cell'].min()/10,10)),df['freq'])`
```

Comment: df.loc[df['freq']<10,'freq_new']=np.minimum((df["freq_cell"]/10),10)
I change the code  a ilttle bit and it worked .  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
df['freq_new'] = np.where(df['freq']<10, np.minimum((df["freq_cell"]/10),10), df['freq'])
```